# Access the third item of a tuple in first element of a list of tuples in django template

Tags: python, django, list, django-templates, tuples

My problem is:
I have a list of tuples as a variable to be accessed in a django template file.

I just want to access the third item of the first tuple in the list.

For example:
If the list is:

```
[(1,2,3,4),(5,6,7,8),(9,10,11,12)]
```

I just want the "3".

I've tried something like:

```
{{lista | first . 3}}
```

and

```
{{(lista | first).3}}
```

But neither of these work.

Comment: The fact that you're looking to extract the "third of the first" anything to me kind of indicates that you either need a class/model to represent data or something may be wrong logically

Comment: It makes sense, but in this case the data came from a raw SQL query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside the template you should be able to use dot notation and [django will unpack it for you](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups):

```
{{ lista.0.2 }}
```

> Dots have a special meaning in template rendering. A dot in a variable name signifies a lookup. Specifically, when the template system encounters a dot in a variable name, it tries the following lookups, in this order:
>
> - Dictionary lookup. Example: `foo["bar"]`
> - Attribute lookup. Example: `foo.bar`
> - List-index lookup. Example: `foo[bar]`